# Can ant generate a unified script including all imports similar to maven's effective pom?

Tags: ant

I have an ant script that imports other scripts which import additional scripts leading to web of places where definitions can happen.

Can ant pull in all the definitions and output a file much like maven's `help:effective-pom`?

I'd like to add this as an output file with my build to make debugging somewhat easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another target which will create that kind of file. For example it can look like this:

main build.xml which do some work and also can generate effective build:

```
<project name="testxml" default="build">

    <import file="build1.xml" />
    <import file="build2.xml" />

    <target name="build">
        <echo>build project</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="effective.build">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\groovy-2.1.4\embeddable\groovy-all-2.1.4.jar" />
        <groovy>
            def regex = ~/import file="(.*)"/
            def buildXmlContent = new File('build.xml').text
            new File('build.xml').eachLine {
                line -> regex.matcher(line).find() {
                    def file = new File(it[1])
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        def replacement = file.getText().replaceAll(/&lt;project.*/, '').replaceAll(/&lt;\/project.*/, '')
                        buildXmlContent = buildXmlContent.replaceFirst(/&lt;import.*/, replacement)
                    }
                }
            }
            new File('build.effective.xml') &lt;&lt; buildXmlContent
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

Two build.xml's created for tests:

```
<project name="testxml2" default="build">
    <target name="clean">
        <echo>clean project</echo>
    </target>
</project>

<project name="testxml1" default="build">
    <target name="test">
        <echo>test project</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

If you will run `ant effective.build` you will get new `build.effective.xml` file with this content:

```
<project name="testxml" default="build">


    <target name="test">
        <echo>test project</echo>
    </target>


    <target name="clean">
        <echo>clean project</echo>
    </target>


    <target name="build">
        <echo>build project</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="effective.build">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\groovy-2.1.4\embeddable\groovy-all-2.1.4.jar" />
        <groovy>
            import java.util.regex.Pattern

            def regex = ~/import file="(.*)"/
            def buildXmlContent = new File('build.xml').text
            new File('build.xml').eachLine {
                line -> regex.matcher(line).find() {
                    def file = new File(it[1])
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        def replacement = file.getText().replaceAll(/&lt;project.*/, '').replaceAll(/&lt;\/project.*/, '')
                        buildXmlContent = buildXmlContent.replaceFirst(/&lt;import.*/, replacement)
                    }
                }
            }
            new File('build.effective.xml') &lt;&lt; buildXmlContent
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

I chose groovy (because I learn it actually) for this purpose but you can create it in another langage. You can also compile this groovy code to ant task and use it as new task, for example `<effectiveant outfile="build.effective.xml">`. My example isn't perfect but it shows one of the solutions.